# salesforce formula field to check null values for Date

Tags: formula

In salesforce I have written the formula field, but its not saving/working properly.

If Completed_Date__c != null && Completed_Date__c < Deadline__c
then Compliant
else
     Violated

```
IF((NOT(ISBLANK(Completed_Date__c))) <  Deadline__c , 'Compliant', 'Violated')
```

If Completed_Date__c not populated then field should show blank.

Comment: Did you try `treat blank as null` in formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this formula.

```
   IF( 
ISBLANK(Completed_Date__c),' ', 
IF( 
Completed_Date__c< Deadline__c , 
'Compliant', 
'Violated' 
))
```

Comment: Thanks ! How can we check if both the Completed_Date__c != null && Deadline__c != null  in the above formula field ?